# How would a lysosome based disease be defeated?

Tags: science-based, earth, diseases

Essentially, in the human world of 2024 (current day tech, but no more COVID), how would humans find a way to prevent a disease that targets and destroys lysosomes, so that only animals are affected. Once the lysosomes are destroyed in the cell, it becomes full of waste materials and ruptures. How would the humans prevent it from destroying all animals?

Edit: it spreads through whatever the most transmissible way to transmit.

Comment: It doesn't matter what part of the cell the virus targets to kill it - all viruses infect and kill cells. Narrow viruses are the ones that are hyper-transmissible because they do one thing really well. After that, it's an immune arms race. The broader the target (all animals) the more generic and less effective a virus tends to be. Since it isn't technically alive, it doesn't "adapt" so much as mutate. A virus generally gets only one or a few transmission vectors. So what you are really asking is, "How do all animals respond to generic viruses - only they're super viruses."

Comment: Surely no different from any other disease that kills cells, which is most of them.

Comment: I thought about it, and while you'd need to do a lot of handwaving, I came up with a vector that could kind-of justify your disease, get a lot of animals, AND have a hypothetical cure.  Good enough for fiction, in any case. See what you think.

Answer (score 7):

Whatever targets the lysosomes is based on molecules, which need to get into the cell to destroy the lysosomes inside it.

The possible approaches to fight the disease are therefore:

- develop a molecule which targets the active molecule of the disease, turning it into an ineffective one
- develop some molecule which inactivates the key which the molecule uses to open the door into the cell, so that it cannot accomplish its mission

Answer (score 7):

## They Probably W/Couldn't do Anything Different:

**Frame Challenge**: This isn't how diseases work. But if the disease was really that bad, it's unlikely they could do anything about it.

- I've added a few scenarios where you could get something CLOSE to what you're looking for, but it would require a fair amount of handwaving.

Lethality is self-limiting for diseases, which is why epidemics and pandemics eventually fade or burn out. The more lethal (like Ebola) the faster they burn out. Usually really serious outbreaks are in diseases that have only recently evolved to affect a new host.

How a disease is vey critical for organisms and needs to be specified for any realistic discussion of how to control it. Each vector has specific pros and cons.

And broad host infection is extremely rare and requires very generalized means of infection, limiting how effective the disease is at both spreading and causing serious infection.

## VIRAL:

If you are going to shut down a fundamental cell function like lysozymes, then the way to do it is to take over the cellular machinery. The only realistic way to do so is with a virus.

Viruses don't come in the "super-kill-everything" variety because they CAN'T. Viruses are not considered technically alive because they are really one-trick ponies. They are incredibly simple, because the more complicated they get, the harder it is to replicate and the more ways a mutation can disable the virus. They evolve a specific vector that targets specific cells, gets inside, and takes over the cell to make more virus. They can get a little fancy after that - hide and re-express later, incorporate into the host to affect later generations, etc. but that just slows them down.

If something about the virus causes the lysozymes to shut down, it would need to somehow give it an advantage in making and spreading viruses. Everything a virus does needs to center around making and spreading the virus. Just destroying the cells is counter-productive. A live host is one spreading the virus and making more. If a virus affects more than one species (or maybe a cluster of species), one of the two species is typically barely affected by the virus so the that species transmits the virus around to the species that is more affected.

The kinds of vectors that viruses use are pretty narrow, because they have to perform a complex task that all animals have spent billions of years developing defenses against. Given generations of exposure, a virus might develop the ability to target a new species, causing a new disease in a new species. But even here, the natural tendency for a virus is to become LESS lethal over time as it adapts to infecting the host without killing it. So each new generation of COVID becomes more transmissible and less deadly. After all, you need those humans to survive.

So the way the virus kills cells is very secondary. If the virus wants to spread, it will quit destroying lysozymes. But even there, a virus only affects the cells it directly infects. So the cells that die stop making virus, stop infecting new cells, and the virus goes extinct.

## NON-VIRAL:

Although the only way I can see a disease shutting down lysosomes is via a virus, Let's look at the nearest equivalent in bacteria. You stand a slightly better chance here, but this is still not how diseases work. even in bacteria, they have limited host ranges OR limited spread OR low lethality.

A bacteria would have a motivation to make itself undetectable to phagocytic cells in their hosts and preventing the cells from getting eaten and digested in lysosomes. A bacteria that could release a broad array of enzyme inhibitors could potentially block the functions of lysosomes, and if those same bacteria were able to tolerate the low pH environment inside, they could theoretically use lysosomes as a refuge inside of macrophages and other phagocytic cells.

There are bacteria that already do something similar, and haven't wiped out animal life yet. [Salmonella and Tuberculosis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7714789/) each have a host of mechanisms that affect the operations of lysosomes. But cellular functions are very complex, and to perform this task the bacteria need to be pretty specialized. Living this way is the biological equivalent of recycling trying to survive on the conveyor bels in a recycling plant. They are intracellular, so they live inside cells (which limits spread but also gives them a protective environment in which to live). But animals have similarly engaged in a billion-year-long war with these organisms, and have a wide variety of defenses to fight them. They also tend to either spread in very limited ways (like feces) or limit themselves to specific hosts.

In these situations as well, the organism lives within the host and relies on the host staying alive for the bacteria to live. Salmonella is fairly aggressive, but needs to be spread but as such triggers strong immune responses and needs to spread in feces (in which case, super-salmonella would be fairly easily controlled by good hygiene among humans, and would be self-limiting among animals as it killed all the available hosts). Tuberculosis spread via the respiratory route, but is successful by spreading very slowly and taking a very long time to degrade the host (as well as specializing in the organisms infected). A super-TB, besides killing the hosts more rapidly due to quick infection, would be a poor fit for killing all animals.

Once again, the disease would only be affecting the cells and lysosomes that it is directly infecting. So the disease would have to be massively infecting almost every cell (or at least almost all of a certain cell type) to work the way you want. If it is only infecting a certain type of tissue, it is likely much more limited in effects from what you're looking for.

**Universal systems**: Diseases that could somehow produce a toxin or hormone that affected all lysosomes in an organism look like the disease you are trying to cause. But these means are more universal in an individual or species, and less universal to all animals. Toxins and hormones will either be so lethal as to cause the disease to burn out almost immediately OR be specific enough that they will only be effective in a single species or category of species. A toxin would be more likely than a hormone, since species aren't likely to have a means of shutting down all of a essential cellular function that will kill the organism.

## IF WE HANDWAVE:

Your disease (Tubercanella) is an intracellular bacteria that can affect **most** animals intestinal tracts and acutely infect the respiratory tracts of mammals. I still don't know you could get EVERYTHING (like fish and insects and even more obscure stuff) but you could get a lot. It has a long incubation time in the hosts, allowing it to persist in organisms and get shed into the environment constantly. Your mammals (notably humans) would be spreading it all over, where it would be difficult to control as it would have reservoirs in non-human animals.

in this case, an [antibiotic](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/10278) would likely be the solution. Only that's too easy for what you want. So it needs to have multidrug resistance (implying it is either genetically engineered OR has been present in a less virulent form among humans for a long time). Antibiotics can be a broad range of substances, typically selectively affecting bacterial enzymes preferentially over animal ones or affecting the bacterial ability to grow and replicate.

After that, the disease would need to be resistant to antibodies or a [vaccine](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/vac-gen/imz-basics.htm) would defeat it easily. Not all bacteria are easy to make vaccines to, so this can be handwaved fairly easily.

If the bacteria is producing a [toxin](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmicb.2016.00042/full#:%7E:text=Bacterial%20toxins%20are%20virulence%20factors,of%20the%20host%20immune%20response.), then a toxin inhibitor or antitoxin could be a treatment. Block the toxin affecting lysosomes and the lysosomes will be unaffected. Since the toxin would likely be essential for the bacteria's spread, this would also effectively be an antibiotic.

- All of these means would work to treat the disease in treated animals and people, but wouldn't work well to spread around to all animals in the environment.

## ****Super-bacteriophage**:**

To actually reduce the global effect of this super-bacteria, you'll need a virus that targets the bacteria. Let's handwave and say the bacteria is significantly suppressing the immune system. To infect an intracellular bacterial disease, that will need to be one hell of a bacteriophage. Bacteriophages are usually a lot more complex than viruses that infect animals, since bacteria are a harder thing to penetrate. It will need to first manage to enter the infested animal cells, then infest the bacteria, without triggering the host immune response against the bacteriophage.

To really get rid of it from the broader environment, you'd need a CRISPR-like virus that somehow integrated into the DNA of **ALL** infected animals and would only get expressed if the cell was infected by the bacteria. Then the virus would kill the bacteria. We likely can't do that today, but trying would certainly be an interesting story.

Comment: Frame challenge challenge: the questions says "disease", not "virus". It might be a bacteria or parasitic amoeboid that produces a chemical/enzyme which is absorbed by the cells, damages the lysosomes so that the cells burst, and then "eats" the spewed contents.

Comment: @Chronocidal Fair, although to do what they want, I think they would need a virus. I added a section on likely bacterial vectors and why they wouldn't work so well either.

Comment: @Joachim Better?